# Self-leveling compound and underlayment

Tags: flooring

We currently decided we are going to be remodeling our kitchen. With that being said I plan to rip up the old hardwood floors all the way down to the sub floor. After cleaning, securing any squeaky or flexing spots in the subfloor I planned on using self leveling compound to flatten everything out. My main question is, Do I lay a new 1/4 in. plywood sub floor ontop of the leveling compound and secure it or would I just start my new flooring project from there? The new flooring will be a floating (hardwood, laminate, or vinyl) floor with a pad underneath. From my understanding I believe I would just start flooring over the leveling compound as screwing down a new 1/4 in. underlayment would crack and crumble the sub floor, but thought I would check with all of you amazing people. Thank you.

Comment: What new flooring are you going to use?  And fair warning - that self leveling stuff is not as easy to use as it might seem and will take a little practice.

Answer (score 1):

You would not install another layer of wood underlayment for your project. You'd apply the flooring pad directly over the cement layer.